# Python pandas CopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Date` column with values like this `2018-02-02 07:00:06.000`. I am trying to replace the column value with only the hour, so replace that date just now into `7`.

-----Update------

Code before the issue

```
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
df.columns = [c.replacec(' ','') for c in df.columns)
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

start = pd.to_datetime('07:00:00:00', format="%H:%M:%S:%f").time()
end = pd.to_datetime('10:59:59:00',format="%H:%M:%S:%f").time()

df_new= df[(df.Date.dt.time >= start) & (df.Date.dt.time <= end)]
```

what I did is

```
df_new.Date = df_new.Date.dt.hour
```

which gives me a warning

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

So then use

```
df_new.loc[:,["Date"]] = df_new.Date.dt.hour
```

But this also gives me the same warning.

Is there a correct or better way to do this?

Comment: What did you do **before** `df.Date = df.Date.dt.hour`?

Comment: @mozway Not much , just ```df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)```

Comment: Then provide the whole code from the beginning

Comment: Ok, I have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning originally arises from a conflict between modifying something in a *view* of a dataframe vs modifying it in a *copy* of the dataframe. Basically, your data slicing method (or even the `.loc` method) can return either a *view* or a *copy* based on how it is used. To make it simple :

- A view is a peek into the original dataframe. Modifying it will modify the original dataframe
- A copy is a sort of a replica of your dataframe from the original, and modifying it has absolutely no effect on the original dataframe.

The problem is, it is hard to predict wether your slicing code will return a *view* or a *copy*. So the most pythonic way to handle it is by creating a copy of your own to begin with like so (see this [documentation](https://www.practicaldatascience.org/html/views_and_copies_in_pandas.html) for more)

```py
df_new= df[(df.Date.dt.time >= start) & (df.Date.dt.time <= end)].copy()
df_new.Date = df_new.Date.dt.hour
```

which should suppress the warning. If the warning still pop when you use the suggested `.loc` method then it is returning a copy rather than a view (hence the warning of setting value on a copy of a slice).

A different method of assining new columns and not use the copy explicitly in your code is [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) :

```py
df_new=df_new.assign(Date = df_new.Date.dt.hour)
```

This bypasses the warning because it actually makes a copy of the dataframe first (it literally starts with `copy()` in the pandas' [implementation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.0/pandas/core/frame.py#L4814-L4880) ).

Eventually, if you just want to silence this warning you can write this after your import

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

Comment: The issue is likely before this step

Comment: Yes it seems that this specific warning can be related to the pandas version. In case the person knows what they're doing with their dataframe while creating new columns, they can just silence these chained assignment warnings with `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`

Comment: @bmasri my pandas version is 1.5.0 If I try to do it at the  beginning to the original ```df``` it doesn't have any warning. However if I perform it on the filtered dataframe ```df_new``` it will produce warnings. And yes, your methods works, but I'm just curious where have i gone wrong

Comment: I have updated my answer to include more explanation on why this warning arises and why other methods work @YYY

Comment: @jezrael Yes thank you. I have updated the answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use the attributes (`df.Date`) but rather the indices (`df['Date']`):

```
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

start = pd.to_datetime('07:00:00:00', format="%H:%M:%S:%f").time()
end = pd.to_datetime('10:59:59:00',format="%H:%M:%S:%f").time()

df_new= df.loc[(df['Date'].dt.time >= start) & (df['Date'].dt.time <= end)]
```

Comment: I still get the warnings after I use indices